Sectoriality of a self-adjoint bounded below operator
Let $A$ be a self-adjoint densely defined operator in a Hilbert space such that $\langle Au,u\rangle\geq\alpha\lVert u\rVert$, $\forall u\in D(A)$, with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. I want to see that this operator is sectorial. Taking $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ and using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality I get the inequality $\lVert(A-\lambda)u\rVert\geq\left|\left\langle A\frac{u}{\lVert u\rVert},\frac{u}{\lVert u\rVert}\right\rangle-\lambda\right|\lVert u\rVert$. Now, since $A$ is self-adjoint, $\sigma(A)\subset\mathbb{R}$. Arguing by contradiction, and using the previous inequality, we can deduce that $\inf\sigma(A)>-\infty$. Let $\lambda_0=\inf\sigma(A)\in\mathbb{R}$. We can then consider the set $S_{\lambda_0,\frac{\pi}{4}}=\left\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}:\frac{\pi}{4}\leq|\operatorname{arg}(\lambda_0-\lambda)|\leq\pi, \lambda\neq\lambda_0\right\}$ (using the notation of D. Henry's book "Geometric Theory of Semilinear Parabolic Equations") is completely contained in the resolvent set of $A$, $\rho(A)$, since it avoids the interval $[\lambda_0,\infty)$.
My problem now is to obtain an upper bound of $\lVert(A-\lambda)^{-1}\rVert$ of the form $C/|\lambda_0-\lambda|$. I've thought of proving $\left|\left\langle A\frac{u}{\lVert u\rVert},\frac{u}{\lVert u\rVert}\right\rangle-\lambda\right|\geq c|\lambda_0-\lambda|$, when $\lambda\in S_{\lambda_0,\frac{\pi}{4}}$. Then using the inequality from the beginning, we would get $\lVert(A-\lambda)u\rVert\geq c|\lambda_0-\lambda|\lVert u\rVert$, and we could finish the argument.
Do you see a way of proving this or is there a better approach to get the desired inequality? Thanks a lot for you help!!

You may assume that $a>0$ (or else consider a translation of $A$). Then
$$ \|(\lambda + A)x \| \ge \lambda \|x\|, \quad \forall \lambda>0, x \in D(B).$$
This follows from
$$\| (\lambda +A)x \| \|x\| \ge | (\lambda x+Ax,x) | \ge \lambda \|x\|^2.$$
Since $\sigma(A)$ is contained in $[0,+\infty)$ you get that
$$ \|(\lambda -A )^{-1}\| \le 1/\lambda, \quad \lambda <0.$$
It is known that this is a sufficient condition for sectoriality. See for instance Proposition 10.1.6 in Analysis in Banach spaces volume II or Lemma 10.33 in  these online functional analysis notes.

Hey! Thanks a lot for taking your time to answer me. I really appreciate it. Just a question. What you mean by $a>0$? It is $\alpha$ on my question? Or $\lambda_0$? Again, thank you very much!

I meant the $a>0$ from the coercivity condition $(Ax,x) \ge a |x|^2$. Although I think you can assume $\lambda_0>0$ as well by looking at $A-\lambda_0$. In both cases you get the dissipative condition $|(A+\lambda)x| \ge \lambda |x|$ on (a translate of) $A$

Sorry, I'm reviewing your comment again and I don't understand how you get the bound $|(\lambda x+Ax,x)|\geq\lambda\lVert x\rVert^2$. How's that reacheable?

This follows from the fact that $A$ is positive $(Ax,x)\ge 0$

Yes, sorry for bothering you with that. Thanks a lot!
